# Flip image in Canvas , without using Scale -1

Tags: css, canvas, html5-canvas, excanvas

I am trying to add flip and flop functionality to this demo http://www.ernestdelgado.com/public-tests/canvasphoto/demo/canvas.html

I am trying by setting scalex = -1 , its works , but this demo also has resize functionality. So author finding height and width (on resizing the image) with scalex (please check below code).

After I am assigning scalex = -1 , the canvas height and width become 0. Is there any other was of doing this?

```
Canvas.Img.prototype.setFlop = function() {
    this.width = this._oElement.width;
    this.height = this._oElement.height;
    this.scalex = -1

    this.setImageCoords();
}

Canvas.Img.prototype.setImageCoords = function() {
    this.left = parseInt(this.left);
    this.top = parseInt(this.top);

    this.currentWidth = parseInt(this.width) * this.scalex;
    this.currentHeight = parseInt(this.height) * this.scalex;
    this._hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.currentWidth / 2, 2) + Math.pow(this.currentHeight / 2, 2));
    this._angle = Math.atan(this.currentHeight / this.currentWidth); ...
```

Comment: I can invert an image for you, but I can't set the canvas to dynamically be flipped in real time without it taking a toll on the engine. 

If you really need real-time in the end you might have to be running two canvases, and one will have to take the data from the other and flip it.

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply, If I am setting ScaleX = -1 , its inverting in realtime. But My problem is "setImageCoords" , which using scaleX value further for all calculation. I can put a "if" statement there and check for negative values of scaleX and change it to positive , but it will not work even. Am i confusing you?